# i recieve an error in mysql DB saying "#1136 column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm currently trying to enter values inside my table "user" via phpmyadmin and that's when I receive an error "#1136 column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

[image: "user" table]

but this error only seems to occur when I have the following trigger entered in my DB, without it the insert works everytime:

[image: This is the trigger]

and this is the table I want to actually "influence" via the trigger above:

[image: "ranking" table]

what i want to do is take the "username" from the table "user" , and the "points" also from "user" table and insert the same values inside the table ranking after every insert into the "user" table

Comment: Please share the code which triggers the error

Comment: Incidentally, "user" is a [keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-U) so it might be safer to always escape it with backticks: `\`user\`.points` etc.

Comment: noted @AndrewMorton but untill something related to that appears then ill change but for now id like to fix the error at hand

Comment: @NicoHaase there is no code that triggers the error the error simply appears while i'm trying to insert into the table "user"

Comment: If the `ranking` table has **three** columns, why does your trigger only contains two of them?

Comment: i actually made it work , im currently trying to figure out how to close the thread, thanks for your help though and to feed your curiosity its because that last value was supposed to be computed not passed via the trigger @NicoHaase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `INSERT`, *always* include the column names:

```
INSERT INTO ranking (col1, col2)  -- whatever the columns are
    VALUES (new.points, new.username);
```

I am not sure what `user.points` and `user.username` are supposed to be.  I imagine you want to include the new values in the `ranking` table.

Comment: right sorry i wasn't clearer , what i want to do is take the "username" from the table "user" , and the "points" also from user table and insert the same values inside the table ranking

Comment: BEGIN
INSERT INTO ranking(ranking.user_name, ranking.Points, ranking.Level) VALUES (user.username, user.points);
END

what about this?